# c.fetchall returns nonetype

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this piece of code that's supposed to select all columns from a table "BTSFinal" where -PCode- is equal to the user's entry -Product_Codev-, insert it into another table -BTSTempt- and select the smallest ID number from it.

```
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET ID=(SELECT ID FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Date_in=(SELECT Date_in FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET PCode=(SELECT PCode FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET PName=(SELECT PName FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),)) 
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Inc_Price=(SELECT Inc_Price FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Quantity_In=(SELECT Quantity_In FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Outg_Price=(SELECT Outg_Price FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Quantity_Out=(SELECT Quantity_Out FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("UPDATE BTSTempt SET Description=(SELECT Description FROM BTSFinal WHERE PCode = ?)",(int(Product_Codev.get()),))
                    c.execute("SELECT MIN(ID) FROM BTSTempt")
                    Minid = c.fetchall()[-1]
                    Minidpre = Minid[0]
                    MinimumID=int(Minidpre)
```

But what I understood from this error

```
MinimumID=int(Minidpre)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Is that there's no match between the "BTSFinal" table in the "PCode" column and the entry which is not the case and I'm absolutely sure that there are matches

Here's the -BTSFinal- table scheme

- ID INTEGER PRIMARYKEY
- Date_in TEXT
- PCode INTEGER
- PName TEXT
- Inc_Price INTEGER
- Quantity_In INTEGER
- Outg_Price INTEGER
- Quantity_Out INTEGER
- Description TEXT

and the scheme of -BTSTempt- is identical to it.
But it always gives me this error that says the -BTSTempt- table is empty which is indeed the case when I try to open it through a sql viewer

Thank you very much and hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this "*there's no match between the "BTSFinal" table in the "PCode" column*" is true is one possiblity. An other possibility is that there is no `BTSTemp` row to update.  That seems more likely. Perhaps the first `UPDATE` should actually be an `INSERT`.

With only the knowledge of what is posted in the question (which is to say no knowledge of what else the `BTSTemp` table will be used for), an easier way to get the  `MIN(ID)` might be:

`"SELECT MIN(ID) from BTSFinal where Pcode = ?)"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice that I was trying to update the table while it's completely empty. Thank you again.